# laplacian of a function, relation to the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose for some function $\Phi$ we have:

$$
\nabla^2 \Phi(\mathbf{r})=\phi(\mathbf{r})
$$

where $\phi(\mathbf{r})$ is some well-behaved smooth function, which is finite everywhere.

Does this mean that $\Phi(\mathbf{r})$ itself doesn't have any singularities?

Could you please point me out any useful theorems?

Comment: What do you mean by the Laplacian of a singular function?

Comment: I was just wondering whether $\Phi$ may have discontinuities or not, if $\phi$ is continous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace operator is *hypoelliptic* (since it's *elliptic* with smooth coefficients) and any hypoelliptic operator $L$ has the property that if $Lf \in C^\infty$, then $f \in C^\infty$.